# Random Crashes with a different programs at fault

Tags: windows-10, drivers, ssd, bsod, crash

I have multiple retail kiosks running LTSC 1809. 1 out of every 5 is getting a BSOD. All the crashes are corruption based and happen around every 4 to 12 hours. I have checked the way I am imaging these machines as well as trying to fix corruption issues with DISM and SFC but have been unable to locate a source for the crashes. Even the crashes have put multiple different programs at fault, the only thing is can guess is that it is putting what every program is currently in use when it crashes. I have multiple minidumps linked below with a Speccy.txt to show hardware specs. Any insight would be appreciated and if anyone needs more info let me know what you need.

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1jJb9GYCe3QYkC1UQRYLK6lkoi5rBEJ8P?usp=sharing

Edit 1/15/2020: The manufacturer has told me all of them are the exact same with minor board changes. I have not by looking been able to determine any difference that shows up in system information between working machines and non-working. USB ports have covers that are screwed down(screws are away from contacting motherboard had that issue with another type of machine). It has been random if reimaging fixing this issue because I have put out three replacement machines one has had the issue recur. One important note is the software running on the kiosks has to be installed when at the store because it grabs information from the server at the store.

Comment: Is the same set of machines crashing repeatedly or just one?  Are all the same hardware?  How long since dust was blown out / fans tested?  Are they running non-privileged users?  Are the kiosks connected to the Internet?  Was the image produced in a clean environment?  If you are re-imaging them, but the problem continues after a few hours, the problem is probably not in the software originally installed.  Do visitors have access to the USB ports so that someone could fool around with the devices?  If you can Edit the question above, please do so.

Comment: Also look in Control Panel, Security and Maintenance, Maintenance, and pull down Reliability History. What applications or processes are causing the issue. Good tool to get started on this.

Comment: Made the changes to question, also thanks for bringing up the Reliability History. Looking to see if it sheds any more light on this issue.

Comment: @Craig Rossiter I don't understand where it say's __Network__ You are not connected to the internet  (also, you should edit that text file and XXX out info which can be read by anyone). Peace

Comment: @vissher Sorry for the confusion this machine was pulled out of the retail environment to my lab and I did not have it connected at the time. These kiosks are wired with static IP

Answer (score 0):

Finally figured out the issue when the manufacturer admitted to changing parts with this order. Ram included had an incompatible issue with the CPU. I was able to change with a different brand of ram and all issues (with a few exceptions) disappeared instantly.